# Rename files on QNAP linux (batch)

Tags: linux, filenames, rename

I have a folder with at least 30 files.

The names are:

> 123456_12_12_AB12_NAME.mp4?BWSQv6seywG5ND2Myt7YM3JHPmaaNmtBRI0PcXbYpqoS01ivTvL0HCHvjfjFtOM9AMq7-kpHUZ0W_m8njEjqBkM9uyngsnKANw

How can I get rid of the string after the ? to end up with just:

> 123456_12_12_AB12_NAME.mp4

I achieve what I want if I use:

```
ls -l | cut -f1 -d"?"
```

But how to put that into a batch file to actually rename the files.

Lastly, do I put the code into a .sh file? or straight from the command line?

Comment: are there any collisions of filenames before the `?`?

Comment: also look at `rename`  by larry wall (it is part of Debian and others). It is `sed` for filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for f in ./*
do
  echo mv -- "$f" "${f%%\?*}"
done
```

Remove the `echo` if the results look correct.  The `?` is a special shell globbing character, and needs to be escaped in order to match directly against the question mark in the filenames.